# prevent regular expression formatting in my javascript

Tags: aptana

I'm sure someone else has asked this but my Google foo is failing me and I cannot find it.
When I divide more than once in an equation like this:

```
this.active[i].pos(last.pos()+(last.width()/2)+10+(this.active[i].width()/2));
```

"**/2)+10+(this.active[i].width()/**" will come up with regular expression formatting(all orange) in the editor which is driving me insane. :(

Is there a way I can change my settings to prevent this?  I do not use regular expression at all, so disabling it's formatting entirely in the editor would be acceptable.

Can anyone provide, or point me towards, an answer?

If you found it on Google, I would appreciate learning your search terms.

Thank you. :)

Comment: I was hoping to make Aptanas editor behave right without having to code around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been searching the web for about 45 minutes trying to find a solution to this very question when I came across this question here on stack overflow. I almost started a bounty on it but decided I'd see if I could figure it out myself.

I came up with two possible solutions, both of which are much simpler than I though they would be.

**Solution 1:** Separate the formula into two sections that can be stored in variables and added together when needed. For example, I happened to be writing a formula for a surface area calculation, which formed a regular expression and returned the incorrect answer:

> > return [(this.base * this.height)/2] + [(this.perimeter * this.slant)/2];

I split the formula at the `+` and stored them in variables:

```
var a = (this.base * this.height)/2;
    var b = (this.perimeter * this.slant)/2;    
    return  a + b
```

This solution worked just fine. But then I started thinking that there had to be a simpler solution I was over-looking which led me to:

**Solution 2:** Dividing by 2 is the same as multiplying by 0.5 (duh!) . In my case - and in almost any case - dividing by 2 and multiplying by 0.5 will get you the same answer. My code then looked like this:

> > return [(this.base * this.height) * 0.5] + [(this.perimeter * this.slant) * 0.5];

I tested both, and both work, though obviously solution 2 is more efficient (less code).

The only time I could imagine needing to use solution 1 is if you're dividing by a very long number or a prime number (dividing by 3 gives you a more accurate result than multiplying by 0.33).

Anyway, I know you posted this question months ago and probably either came up with a solution or moved on, but I figured I'd post this answer anyway as a reference for any future issues with the same idea.

(Also, this is in JavaScript but I can't imagine something this simple is any different in a similar language).